# Adding a member in google groups by python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to add a member in google groups created in googlegroups. I have tried 'Provisioning API' but unable to use it.

```
groupClient=gdata.apps.groups.client.GroupsProvisioningClient(domain='groups.google.com')
groupClient.ClientLogin(email='myusername@googlegroups.com', password='myPassword', source='apps')
groupClient.AddMemberToGroup('test', 'emailToAdd@gmail.com')
```

Is it correct? I am getting the error `Invalid domain`, I have tried several methods but unable to do anything.